# Is it possible to define an operation on a set of boolean matrices so that they form a semigroup without also forming a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given G = the set of all nxn boolean matrices. Is is possible to define an operation $\circ$ on this set in such a fashion that G, $\circ$ forms a semi-group without also beeing a group. Are there any practical examples of these kinds of semi-groups?

Comment: Sure; take componentwise AND or OR.

Comment: Matrix multiplication fits the bill.

Comment: Wouldn't ordinary matrix multiplication violate the closure property of a semigroup?

Comment: Do multiplication in $\mathbb F_2$

Comment: Or just define the product of any two matrices to be the zero matrix.

Comment: @mathsmathsmaths Why do you think so? Matrix multiplication is associative for matrices over any semiring.

Comment: I'm guessing from your comment @Maths that you're not familiar with the ring structure on the set $\{0,1\}$ where xor is addition and and is multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples, but you can use a semigroup known as the *universal counterexample* in semigroup theory. Take the set of matrices
$$
 B_2 = \left\{  
 \begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}, 
 \begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}, 
 \begin{pmatrix} 0&0 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}, 
 \begin{pmatrix} 0&0 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}, 
 \begin{pmatrix} 0&0 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}
 \right\}
$$
under usual multiplication of matrices --- or under Boolean operations --- the result is the same. There is no unit in this semigroup, and hence, it is not a group. In fact, even if you add the identity matrix, no element of $B_2$ will have an inverse.